# How to break a long string and make it continue on the next line?

Tags: html, css

Assuming the extreme case where I get a long string that has no white space and I want to break it into the next line, how can I do that? [Currently it moves the whole string to the second line and then breaks on the third.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLunc.png) How can I make it so the string starts right after the username, breaks at the end of that line and then continues for the next 2?

```css
#chat {
  height: 300px;
  width: 95%;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.message {
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid #CACACA;
  line-height: 150%;
}

.username {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat">
  <span><p class="message"><span class="timestamp">[15/06/2017 6:15] </span><span class="username">Username: </span>asjdqwljdawjdh</p>
  </span>
  <span><p class="message"><span class="timestamp">[15/06/2017 6:15] </span><span class="username">Username: </span>spanasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdh</p>
  </span>
  <span><p class="message"><span class="timestamp">[15/06/2017 6:15] </span><span class="username">Username: </span>asjdqwljdawjdh</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe [`overflow-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)? Or [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)? (Those are links you can click)

Comment: user8296390, remember to mark one of the provided answers as *accepted* (tick mark on the left hand side) in order to mark your question as *solved*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use something like:

```
p.test {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is with `textarea`

```css
textarea {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea>dfhiasfausdhfuasdfasdufasfuadsfasudfads</textarea>
```

Comment: Good thinking; this might be more what OP is looking for, given that they seem to be showing a chat log.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, you are wrapping each `.message` (those are `p`) in a `span`. However, `span` is an inline-element and can only contain other inline-elements, but `p` is a block-level element. I therefore suggest to remove the additional `span`.

**Second**, use [`word-break: break-all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) on `.message` instead of `word-break: break-word` (which is an invalid value) on `#chat`, that should do the trick:

```css
#chat {
  height: 300px;
  width: 95%;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.message {
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid #CACACA;
  line-height: 150%;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.username {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat">
  <p class="message"><span class="timestamp">[15/06/2017 6:15] </span><span class="username">Username: </span>asjdqwljdawjdh</p>
  <p class="message"><span class="timestamp">[15/06/2017 6:15] </span><span class="username">Username: </span>spanasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdh</p>
  <p class="message"><span class="timestamp">[15/06/2017 6:15] </span><span class="username">Username: </span>asjdqwljdawjdh</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the CSS of `#chat`. You need to replace

```
word-break: break-word;
```

With

```
word-break: break-all;
```

The reason this works, is that `break-word` as a value of `word-break` doesn't exist. You're confusing it with `overflow-wrap`, which *does* have a value of `break-word`.

Values of [`overflow-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap):

> /* Keyword values */
>   overflow-wrap: normal;
>   overflow-wrap: break-word;
>
> /* Global values */
>   overflow-wrap: inherit;
>   overflow-wrap: initial;
>   overflow-wrap: unset;

And the values of [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break):

> /* Keyword values */
>   word-break: normal;
>   word-break: break-all;
>   word-break: keep-all;
>
> /* Global values */
>   word-break: inherit;
>   word-break: initial;
>   word-break: unset;

```css
#chat {
  height: 300px;
  width: 95%;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.message {
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid #CACACA;
  line-height: 150%;
}

.username {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat">
  <span><p class="message"><span class="timestamp">[15/06/2017 6:15] </span><span class="username">Username: </span>asjdqwljdawjdh</p>
  </span>
  <span><p class="message"><span class="timestamp">[15/06/2017 6:15] </span><span class="username">Username: </span>spanasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhspanasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdhasjdqwljdawjdh</p>
  </span>
  <span><p class="message"><span class="timestamp">[15/06/2017 6:15] </span><span class="username">Username: </span>asjdqwljdawjdh</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css for your chat:

```
#chat {  
  height: 300px;  
  width: 100%;  
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;  
  background-color: #f8f8f8;  
  text-align: left;  
  padding: 5px;  
  font-size: 13px;  
  display: inline-block;  
  overflow-y: scroll;  
  word-break: break-all;  
}
```

Hope this helps.